# I have to make a program that asks an input from the user for the height of a triangle

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say the user inputs an integer h where h >= 0.

```
SAMPLE INPUT:
1
SAMPLE OUTPUT:
*

SAMPLE INPUT:
3
SAMPLE OUTPUT:
  *
 ***
*****
```

This is my code. However, I can't seem to properly align the asterisks to make a proper triangle.

```
n = int(input())
def triangle(n):
    a = n
    b = 0
    c = 1
    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(0, a):
            print(end=" ")
        a = a - 1
        for k in range (0, i):
            print("*"*(c+b), end=" ")
            print("\r")
            b = b + 1
            c = c + 1
print(triangle(n))
```

Comment: For sample input "n=3" just think: How many spaces do you need in the first row before the asterisk and how is the number related to "n"?

Comment: Since I have done these exercises for more than 20 times in my life. First draw them on a paper for different n's. Then try to figure out what is the formula for spaces (general formula). Then apply it to python

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.  "I can't seem to do it" is not a problem specification.

Comment: Also check [can someone help me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  You didn't describe it in just those words, but the lack of specific tracing in your code suggests that you have in mind some personal tutoring -- which is out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a slightly different approach where you utilize the fact that for each row, the number of stars will be, `2 * row - 1`:

```
def print_triangle(height: int) -> None:
    base = 2 * height - 1
    for row in range(1, height + 1):
        num_stars = 2 * row - 1
        num_left_spaces = (base - num_stars) // 2
        for _ in range(num_left_spaces):
            print(" ", end="")
        for _ in range(num_stars):
            print("*", end="")
        print()

def get_int_input(prompt: str) -> int:
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print("Error: Enter an integer, try again...")

n = get_int_input("Enter the height of the triangle: ")
print_triangle(n)
```

**Example Usage 1:**

```
Enter the height of the triangle: 1
*
```

**Example Usage 2:**

```
Enter the height of the triangle: 3
  *
 ***
*****
```

**Example Usage 3:**

```
Enter the height of the triangle: 5
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. However, I did not use the get_int_input function, rather I used conditionals for that. Nevertheless, thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
 def triangle(n):
    k = 2 * n - 2

    for i in range(0, n):

        for j in range(0, k):
            print(end=" ")

        k = k - 1

        for j in range(0, i + 1):
            
            print("* ", end="")

        print("\r")
n = int(input("Enter value:"))
triangle(n)
```

visit below link for more info
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/programs-printing-pyramid-patterns-python/

Comment: This is incorrect have a look at the picture it has extra spaces in between adjacent asterisks, which OP does not want.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())
def triangle(n):
    for i in range(0, n):
        space_count = n-i-1
        asterisk_count = n-space_count+i
        print("{0}{1}".format(
            " " * space_count,
            "*" * asterisk_count)
        )

triangle(n)
```

Sample Output:

```
10
         *
        ***
       *****
      *******
     *********
    ***********
   *************
  ***************
 *****************
*******************
```

After copying the code above, run the following:

```
echo '#!/usr/bin/env python\n\n'"$(pbpaste)" > /tmp/triangulo.py && \
 chmod +x /tmp/triangulo.py && \
 for i in {0..20}; do; \
  /tmp/triangulo.py <<< $i; \
 done;
```